# Updating value in DB laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
    if(Auth::user())
    {
    Auth::user()->points = $request->points + 100;
    Auth::user()->save();
    }
```

Everytime user hits submit button in comment box, he should get +100 points, the problem is when I hit submit, comment is saved and points is saved. For example if I had 0 points or more no matter how many, after every comment it's still keeps showing that I have 100. It seems that I can add another 100 to existing points, it just change the value it self and not adding more points.

Comment: You already have your answer, but to comment on this code: probably `$request->points` has a value of `0` (or nothing at all, thus resulting in `null` which is equal to `0` if you're doing math), thus `0` + `100` = `100`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try assigning it this way:

```
Auth::user()->points += 100;
```

If I understood your case correctly.

Basically you might wanna make sure that the `$request->points` has the correct value. Or simply increase the value the user holds.

Another way to try is:

```
Auth::user()->increment('points', 100);
```

More about that [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#updates)

Comment: Yeah it's working right now! I will accept your answer after 10 minutes!

Comment: Great! as long as it helped you understand what was the problem